# Zf2 layout css and javascript paths do not resolve on child routes

Tags: javascript, php, css, zend-framework2

Currently I am trying to setup segment routes that all use the same template.  Currently the base route /my-dashboard view uses a layout.  This works for the base route.  But after trying to add a child segment route the layout css and js paths are incorrect.  I would like any segment under /my-dashboard/ideas /my-dashboard/whatever /my-dashboard/whatever/update/777 to use the same layout but just with different views.  And the layout to have the correct css and js paths for every view.

route.config.php

```
'dashboard' => array(
        'type' => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/my-dashboard',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'dashboard',
                'action'     => 'dashboard',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'wahtever' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/ideas',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'ideas',
                            'action'     => 'ideas',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
    ),
```

If I go to the /my-dashboard it will show the correct view with the layout i want to use for any of these routes.  If I go to /my-dashboard/ideas, the route resolves but when looking in the console all the css and js is screwed up with 404s cant find such and such.  If I add ../ inside the layout it will work on the nested route but then will screw up the /my-dashboard route.

module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/my-dashboard-layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/my-dashboard-layout.twig',
        'wmi/dashboard/dashboard'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/dashboard/dashboard.twig',
        'wmi/ideas/ideas'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/ideas/ideas.twig',
    )
),
```

Edit to add layout and view.
layout/my-dashboard-layout.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/default_skin/css/theme.css">

    <!-- Admin Panels CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin-tools/admin-plugins/admin-panels/adminpanels.css">

    <!-- Admin Forms CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin-tools/admin-forms/css/admin-forms.css">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body class="dashboard-page sb-l-o sb-r-c">
    <!-- Start: Content-Wrapper -->
    <section id="content_wrapper">
        {% block content %}{{ content|raw }}{% endblock content %}
    </section>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the css and javascript paths are what I'm referring to.  On the base literal route /my-dashboard the layout and view shows correctly.  Though when you go to the segment portion /my-dashboard/ideas you get the 404 can't find whatever inside the browser console.

```
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/admin-tools/admin-plugins/admin-panels/adminpanels.css 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/admin-tools/admin-forms/css/admin-forms.css 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/img/avatars/2.jpg 
404 (Not Found) 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/bootstrap/holder.min.js
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/circles/circles.js
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/raphael/raphael.js
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/highcharts/highcharts.js 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/admin-tools/admin-plugins/admin-panels/adminpanels.css 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/admin-tools/admin-forms/css/admin-forms.css  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/img/avatars/2.jpg 
404 (Not Found) 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js 
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/bootstrap/holder.min.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/circles/circles.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/raphael/raphael.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/components/highcharts/highcharts.js  
GET http://watch.dev/my-dashboard/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js 
404 (Not Found)
```

ideas/my-ideas.twig

```
{% extends "layout/my-dashboard-layout" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help is appreciated. 404(Not Found)

ideas/my-ideas.twig

```
{% extends "layout/my-dashboard-layout" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably post your markup and config (if applicable) for the css and js. Are you using the asset manager?

Comment: What is the asset manager?  Ill try to add more information to the paths i'm talking about.

Comment: You can read the docs here https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager basically it allows assets to be served from vendor modules etc. You don't have to be using it just helps to bugfix to know if you are

Comment: The asset manager looks like symfonys way of moving assets.  Though this looks good I don't think it is the problem.  Because even after files get moved to the public directory pragmatically or manually, the paths in the layout and views stay the same.  I wonder if I have to use the basePath() view helper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a ZF problem, as CSS/JS requests shouldn't even touch PHP. Because you are using relative paths in your layout, the browser is loading the CSS and JS files relative to the current URL. E.g. when you're on `/my-dashboard/ideas` page, it's trying to load `/my-dashboard/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css` (which is not the correct URL).

To fix this, always use absolute paths in your layout, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css">
```

(note the initial slash at the start of the href path). This ensures your assets will always load from the document root.

Comment: Your awesome!  That fixes the problem.  I didn't know that the slash before made that difference.  Thankyou for the quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

It's also good habit to use basePath view plugin like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->basePath('css/theme.css'); ?>" />
```

So if in the future path to your app will change you will not have to change this all src's and href's paths in view files.